# Asp net jquery code behind

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I'm still new to asp.net. I'm trying to learn asp net by trying to render aspx in some part only. It worked but I made a button textbox and label and make the label take text from the textbox, when button clicked.

*Here my code* :
Detault.aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div align="center"><h1>THIS IS MASTER PAGE</h1></div>
        <hr />
        <a href="Javascript:void(0)" onClick="return doNothing()">tes</a>
        <a href="Javascript:void(0)" onClick="return doNothing2()">tes2</a>
        <hr />
        <div id="conteted"></div>
    </div>
</form>
<script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function doNothing() {
        $("#conteted").load("tes2.aspx");
        return false;
    };
    function doNothing2() {
        $("#conteted").load("tes3.aspx");
        return false;
    };
</script>
```

This is the tes3.aspx:

```
 <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server">aaaa</asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="Btn" runat="server" Text="sing"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

tes3.aspx.vb

```
Protected Sub Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn.Click
    Label1.Text = Textbox1.Text
End Sub
```

Is there anything wrong or I passed something wrong ?

Comment: Because you have loaded the contents of tes3.aspx into a different page, then you lose the code behind click event.

Comment: how to make it work then ? sorry im still really new to this

Answer (score 0):

Simply use some jQuery instead of server side code, as you lose the asp.net click events when you load content dynamically to a different page.

For example:

```
 <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">aaaa</asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="Btn" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="sing"/>
    </div>
    </form>

   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#Btn').click(function(){
         $('#Label1').text() = $('#Textbox1').val();
      })
   })
   </script>
</body>
```

You will need jQuery library loaded as well

Comment: jquery already loaded and it work but is there no way to load the code behind ? or other way that can partial render the page cause i dont want all the page rendered